# JavaScript wait for asynchronous function in if statement

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, passport.js

I have a function inside an if statement

isLoggedin() has an async call.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.isLoggedin()){ <- never returns true
        console.log('Authenticated!');
    } else {
        console.log('Unauthenticated');
    }
});
```

how do i await for isLoggedin() in this if statement?

here is my isLoggedin function in which im using passport

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   req.isLoggedin = () => {
        //passport-local
        if(req.isAuthenticated()) return true;

        //http-bearer
       passport.authenticate('bearer-login',(err, user) => {
           if (err) throw err;
           if (!user) return false;
           return true;

       })(req, res);
   };

   next();
});
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I do this exact thing using `async/await` in my games code [here](https://github.com/RUJodan/Source-React/blob/master/routes/waitingRoom.js)

Assuming `req.isLoggedIn()` returns a boolean, it's as simple as:

```
const isLoggedIn = await req.isLoggedIn();
if (isLoggedIn) {
    // do login stuff
}
```

Or shorthand it to:

```
if (await req.isLoggedIn()) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Make sure you have that inside an `async` function though!

Comment: is there a way to use process.nextTick() instead? because i want to keep my syntax if(req.isLoggedin()){}

Comment: Any particular reason why? I don't think synchronizing to the next event loop has a benefit over a Promise

Comment: because i want to keep my syntax if(req.isLoggedin()){} :) would it be much more inefficient?

Comment: The efficiently would be negligible, but `nextTick` does hold a higher efficiency because Promises create 2 and throws away one, but tbh I've never used nextTick to handle async behavior and I don't really know too many who do. I'll have to do some more research

Comment: @pfMusk **Please** don't use process.nextTick for this. Just make the function `async` and use `await`, you-in-6-months would thank you.

Comment: okok thank you @MadaraUchiha

Comment: This answer is wrong. Putting `await` before a function call that returns a boolean, will not await the asynchronous `authenticate` process that the Asker has. I don't understand why this was marked as accepted.

Answer (score 13):

You could *promisify* your function, like this:

```
req.isLoggedin = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //passport-local
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) return resolve(true);

    //http-bearer
   passport.authenticate('bearer-login', (err, user) => {
       if (err) return reject(err);
       resolve(!!user);
   })(req, res);
});
```

And then you can do:

```
req.isLoggedin().then( isLoggedin => {
    if (isLoggedin) {
        console.log('user is logged in');
    }
}).catch( err => {
    console.log('there was an error:', err); 
});
```

Do not try to keep the synchronous pattern (`if (req.isLoggeedin())`), as it will lead to poorly designed code. Instead, *embrace* fully the asynchronous coding patterns: anything is possible with it.